# What can I do about WinExist() taking up a good amount of I/O?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a loop that works like this:

```
Loop {
    ; Do something here.

    If (WinExist("ThisWindow")) {
        ; Do stuff here.
    }

    Sleep, 10
}
```

However, it seems that as soon as I added `WinExist()` in the loop, it starts doing some sizable I/O as can be seen in Process Explorer. I've already tried separating the `WinExist()` check to a `SetTimer` instead of inside the `Loop` but it still does it. Does anyone have any idea of alternatives I can do use? I wanted to use `WinWait` instead but surprisingly. that also uses up I/O. And I can't have the loop get interrupted or paused.

Is this something I cannot work around? This is a script constantly running in the background so I want to optimize it as much as I can.

[image]

**Update**
It seems to be related to me setting `SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx`. So it happens when `RegEx` is enabled

Comment: Have you tried changing `Sleep, 10` to `Sleep, 1000`?

Comment: Possible performance optimizations really depend on what your script is doing. Are you positive that exactly the `Win...` commands are responsible for that? On my machine, a script simply containing a `WinWait` command doesn't generate nearly as much I/O. It might be helpful if you provided more of your code. Is the amount of I/O generated a problem in the first place? Anyway, [ShellHook](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/80644-how-to-hook-on-to-shell-to-receive-its-messages/) is another, more event-driven way to listen for active/existing windows. Maybe you can play around with that.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The example you gave does not cause any io reads at all. The script uses almost no resource.

Comment: @MCL I ran my script with and without `WinExist()` and the I/O only occured when it was included. My `WinExist()` section is only meant to center a window to the screen

Comment: @2501 I've just verified that it happens with `SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx`

Comment: That makes sense, regex is slow.

Comment: So is there a way to get around it? What other approach can I do?

Comment: Try creating a windows group in the auto-execute section using "WinGet, id, list, ahk_class ThisClass" and replacing "If (WinExist("ThisWindow"))" with "If (WinExist("ahk_group Groupname"))" in the loop without RegEx.